# Convert a PHP code to Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

At the moment i'm learning a bit of Coldfusion coding and i'm converting my whole old PHP website into sleek Coldfusion code, but i'm stuck with a few lines of PHP and i really don't know how i should convert these lines of code into a proper Coldfusion code:

```
function access()   
{   
  $accesscode = $_GET["accesscode"];
  $time = (int)$_GET["time"];        
  $ip = $_GET["ip"];                

  // Time variable must be identical 
  if( time() < $time )  
      {  
      die("Locale time is ". (time()-$time) ."sec. is not correct.");  
      }  

 // Check client IP
  if( $ip <> $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] )  
      {  
      die("Client IP ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]." is not identical as ".$ip." used."); 
      }  

  // Time > 10 minutes is no access
  for ($c=0;$c<=3;$c++)   
    {   
    $t = substr(strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M", time()-($c*600)),0,11);   
    $hash = md5($ip. "9709f31be0". $t);   
    if( $hash == $accesscode ) return true;  
    }  

return false;  
}  

if (!access())      
{   
  die ("Access denied..");   
}   
Echo "Access approved.";
```

If anyone could help to give me some tips on how to convert these lines of code, i would be very greatfull.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: What stucks you? Date formating?

Comment: You need to be more specific, a lot of this is very basic code and you can easily google "php time() coldfusion" and come up with Now(), etc.

Comment: Pretty much all of it, but i'll google the php time() coldfusion. Thanks.

Comment: Small tip, `_GET` and `_SERVER` are the `URL` and `CGI` scopes in ColdFusion. Also, most CF functions have descriptive names. So if you know what a function does in php, chances are you can find the corresponding CF function just by checking the [functions by category list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html)

Comment: Really disappointed this question was closed. It is often useful to see what a function looks like ported from one language to another -- especially if the port was further annotated or revised to suggest best practices for the target language. ...that said, I agree the title is too broad.

Comment: Disagree that this question is too localised: it's asking some useful things like the PHP/CF equivalents of URL and CGI variables, what various function equivalents are, etc.  Useful stuff.  Would be better if the close-voters would just help the person instead of being pompous about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of ways you could do it... but I've had to make some assumptions since I don't know a lot about php.

```
<cffunction name="access" access="public" returntype="struct">
  <cfargument name="accesscode" type="string" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="time" type="string" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="ip" type="string" required="yes">

  <cfset var temp = StructNew()>
  <cfset temp.time = Now()>
  <cfset temp.errormsg = "">

  <cfif temp.time lt arguments.time>
     <cfset temp.errormsg = "(your error message here)">
  </cfif>

  <cfif cgi.remote_addr neq arguments.ip>
     <cfset temp.errormsg = "(your error message here)">
  </cfif>

  <cfloop index="temp.c" from="0" to="3">
     <!--- not entirely sure what you were doing in here --->
  </cfloop>


  <cfreturn temp>

</cffunction>

<cfset result = access(accesscode="something", time="something", ip="something")>

<cfif result.errormsg neq "">
   <!--- access denied --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: The part you didn't know what to do is just a simple check if a time limit has been reached. Eg. after code (time string) is created, you can't use it any more after 10 minutes. Thanks for you help!